# change image in a circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button and a function that on click changes the background image

But it only works once. How can I make so that the click button always works and the change of images does not stop, but changes in turn?

```js
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/187/200/200.jpg?hmac=b_8v5WKwO-_jC2FqfZOP_n9niD1jQvZHB31GoegK2Ww)";
}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/1008/200/200.jpg?hmac=I0T_cpYR-61pUlB0jVB4I5B7tL0fvzN5MgslAOirM50");
}
  
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>

<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: will you please elaborate your question properly? What does it mean, How can I make it change in a circle?

Comment: @RahulDaksh so that the click button always works and the change of images does not stop, but changes in turn

Comment: Please check out my answer mentioned below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
               document.getElementById("image").classList.toggle("newBg");
            }
```

```css
 #image {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-image: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/1008/200/200.jpg?hmac=I0T_cpYR-61pUlB0jVB4I5B7tL0fvzN5MgslAOirM50");
    }
   
   
   #image.newBg{
    background-image: URL("https://i.picsum.photos/id/187/200/200.jpg?hmac=b_8v5WKwO-_jC2FqfZOP_n9niD1jQvZHB31GoegK2Ww");
    }
      
    button {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>
    
    <div id="image"></div>
```

If you want to change the image with every click, you need to toggle it. You can simply use a class-based approach out of many other solutions.

Eg:

```
function myFunction() {
           document.getElementById("image").classList.toggle("newBg");
        }

#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/1008/200/200.jpg?hmac=I0T_cpYR-61pUlB0jVB4I5B7tL0fvzN5MgslAOirM50");
}

#image.newBg{
background-image: URL("https://i.picsum.photos/id/187/200/200.jpg?hmac=b_8v5WKwO-_jC2FqfZOP_n9niD1jQvZHB31GoegK2Ww");
}
  
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>

<div id="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this js file .it will be work.

```
const id=document.getElementById("image");
let num=1;
async function myFunction() {
 while(true){
    await sleep();
 }  
 }

async function sleep(){

const slp= await fun();
console.log("2 sec later ");
createImg();
}

function fun(){
const promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
setTimeout(function(){
    resolve("");
},2000)
})
return promise;
}
function createImg()
{
    let url = `url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=${num})`;
    id.style.backgroundImage=url;
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a CSS element called border radius
apply this to the image and it will gonna change  into circle

```
border-radius: 50%;
```